# List of ints to string

Tags: python, string, char, int

I have a list of ints:

```
(83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115)
```

which I believe codes for `Siemens`.

How can I convert this list to a string in a pythonic way?

I know I can get the individual chars with `chr(x)` and concatenate them but that doesn't seem the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytes) (or [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytes)) and [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> bytes(bytearray((83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115)))
'Siemens'
```

---

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> bytes((83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115)).decode()
'Siemens'
```

Comment: We don't need the `bytes` actually.

Comment: @thefourtheye, I'm sorry. I don't get it.

Comment: Without `bytes` also we ll get the same results, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye, OP wants string. So explicitly convert it to `str` (`bytes` in Python 2.x == `str`). `bytearray` lacks some methods. (`format`, `%`), and works differently when indexed.

Comment: But, in Python 3.x, `type(bytearray(data).decode())` is `str`. Why do we need the `bytes`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, I removed `bytearray` call from `bytes(bytearray((83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115))).decode()`. It seems like you're seeing older version which was edited in grace time.

Answer (score 4):

```
t = (83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115)
print "".join(map(chr,t))
Siemens
```

Answer (score 2):

For every number in the data, apply `chr` function to get the corresponding character and then concatenate all the characters together to get the actual string, like this

```
print "".join(chr(item) for item in (83, 105, 101, 109, 101, 110, 115))
# Siemens
```